# Delete nan AND corresponding elements in two same-length array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have two lists of the same length that I can convert into array to play with the [numpy.stats.pearsonr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html) method. Now, some of the elements of these lists are `nan`, and can thus not be used for that method. The best thing to do in my case is to remove those elements, and the corresponding element in the other list. Is there a practical and pythonic way to do it?
Example: I have

`[1 2 nan 4 5 6 ]` and `[1 nan 3 nan 5 6]`

and in the end I need

`[1 5 6 ]`

`[1 5 6 ]`

(here the number are representative of the position/indices, not of the actual numbers I am dealing with). EDIT: The tricky part here is to have both lists/arrays without `nan`s in one array AND elements corresponding to `nan`s in the other, and vice versa. Although it can certainly be done by manipulating the arrays, I am sure there is a clear and not overcomplicated way to do it in a pythonic way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The accepted answer to proposed duplicate gets you half-way there. Since you're using Numpy already you should make these into numpy arrays. Then you should generate an indexing expression, and then use it to index these 2 arrays. Here indices will be a new array of `bool` of same shape where each element is `True` iff not (respective element in x is `nan` or respective element in y is `nan`):

```
>>> x
array([  1.,   2.,  nan,   4.,   5.,   6.])
>>> y
array([  1.,  nan,   3.,  nan,   5.,   6.])
>>> indices = np.logical_not(np.logical_or(np.isnan(x), np.isnan(y)))
>>> x = x[indices]
>>> y = y[indices]
>>> x
array([ 1.,  5.,  6.])
>>> y
array([ 1.,  5.,  6.])
```

Notably, this works for any 2 arrays of same shape.

P.S., if you know that the element type in the operand arrays is boolean, as is the case for arrays returned from `isnan` here, you can use `~` instead of `logical_not` and `|` instead of `logical_or`: `indices = ~(np.isnan(x) | np.isnan(y))`

Comment: I think the recommended way is to use the boolean operators of numpy: `numpy.logical_not` and  `numpy.logical_and` together with `numpy.isnan`.

Comment: Clear, easy and well explained. And it works. thanks!

Comment: @Bort perhaps, but `isnan` already returns booleans, so `~` and `|` will work as well.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Since a lot of matlab people think of  ~ | as logical operators but they are bitwise operators in numpy, it is a regular source of confusing errors. That's why I added my comment and upvoted your solution.