# Removing NaN elements from 2 arrays?

Tags: python, list

I asked a question here a few weeks back and got great feedback! I have another question I am a bit stuck with. I have 2 very large lists (of the same size), and each one has some np.nan values throughout. The locations of these nan values are not the same between the 2 lists. I need to cycle through the first list, and delete the nan values in it, and the corresponding values in the second list (the values at the index where the nan value occurred in the first list). I then need to do this for the second list. Any tips on a fast, efficient way to do this? I will be eventually be dealing with very large data sets. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how efficient this is, but you can use `nansInArray1 = np.isnan(array1)` to get a numpy array of bools that correspond to the indices with np.nan in array 1. Then do

`array1 = array1[~nansInArray1]`

`array2 = array2[~nansInArray1]`

Then repeat for array2.

Again, I am completely unsure of whether or not this is efficient, I'm quite new to python.

I'm also assuming array1 and array2 and numpy arrays.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this link out:- It offers an implementation of the first answer on this thread. [Delete nan AND corresponding elements in two same-length array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540782/delete-nan-and-corresponding-elements-in-two-same-length-array).

This is what worked for me

```
indices = np.logical_not(np.logical_or(np.isnan(x), np.isnan(y)))     
indices = np.array(indices)
x = x[indices]
y = y[indices]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumarete to iterate with an index.

```
for idx, value in enumerate(list):
  if(value=Nan): other_list.remove(idx)
  else: new_filtered_list.add(value)
```

But that's not a really fast solution, and you can't delete from "list" while you iterate it, so you have to create a new one.
I think the best method if you are looking for performance, is to simply use a for loop.

You can try both and do a benchmark if you wish, but pyhton is not really a very quick language, if you need performance, you should code this in C and the use it in your python code.