Mismatch between periodogram calculated by SciPy periodogram and AstroPy Lomb Scargle periodogram at low frequencies
I am trying to compute the periodogram of my data using both SciPy's periodogram and AstroPy Lomb-Scargle periodogram—the periodogram matches everywhere except at frequencies near the minimum frequency as shown in my plots. These are the results of numerical simulations.
Based on observational data, I expect a strong signal near 0. Hence, the SciPy periodogram results look more physically plausible than the Lomb-Scargle periodogram.
I haven't figured out why and how to make them similar. Any insight is deeply appreciated.
Below is the code to reproduce my plots.
From standard SciPy periodogram:

From Lomb-Scargle periodogram:

from astropy.timeseries import LombScargle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import signal
import requests 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def plot_periodogram(x,y,N_freq,min_freq,max_freq,height_threshold,periodogram_type): 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))

if periodogram_type == 'periodogram':
    dx = np.mean(np.diff(x))  # Assume x is uniformly sampled
    fs = 1 / dx

    freq, power_periodogram = signal.periodogram(y,fs,scaling="spectrum",nfft=N_freq,
                                                     return_onesided=True,detrend='constant')
    power_max = power_periodogram[~np.isnan(power_periodogram)].max()
    
    plt.plot(freq, power_periodogram/power_max,linestyle="solid",color="black",linewidth=2)
    
    filename = "PowerSpectrum"
    
else:
    
    freq = np.linspace(min_freq,max_freq,N_freq)
    ls= LombScargle(x, y,normalization='psd',nterms=1)
    power_periodogram= ls.power(freq)
            
    power_max = power_periodogram[~np.isnan(power_periodogram)].max()
    
    false_alarm_probabilities = [0.01,0.05]
    periodogram_peak_height= ls.false_alarm_level(false_alarm_probabilities,minimum_frequency=min_freq, 
                                                  maximum_frequency=max_freq,method='bootstrap')
    
    filename = "PowerSpectrum_LombScargle"
    plt.plot(freq, power_periodogram/power_max,linestyle="solid",color="black",linewidth=2)
    plt.axhline(y=periodogram_peak_height[0]/power_max, color='black', linestyle='--')
    plt.axhline(y=periodogram_peak_height[1]/power_max, color='black', linestyle='-')



peaks_index, properties = signal.find_peaks(power_periodogram/power_max, height=height_threshold)    
peak_values = properties['peak_heights']
peak_power_freq = freq[peaks_index]

for i in range(len(peak_power_freq)):
    plt.axvline(x = peak_power_freq[i],color = 'red',linestyle='--')
    ax.text(peak_power_freq[i]+0.05, 0.95, str(round(peak_power_freq[i],2)), color='red',ha='left', va='top', rotation=0,transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform())

   
fig.patch.set_alpha(1)   
plt.ylabel('Spectral Power',fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Spatial Frequency', fontsize=20)
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlim(left=min_freq,right=max_freq)
   
plt.xticks(fontsize=20)
plt.yticks(fontsize=20)
plt.savefig(filename,bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()




# URL of the CSV file on Pastebin
url = 'https://pastebin.com/raw/uFi8WPvJ'

# Fetch the raw data from the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Decode the response content to text
    data = response.text
    
    # Save the data to a CSV file
    with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
        f.write(data)
        
df =pd.read_csv('data.csv',sep=',',comment='%', names=['x', 'Bphi','r','theta'])
x = df['x'].values
y = df['Bphi'].values

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540782/delete-nan-and-corresponding-elements-in-two-same-length-array
indices = np.logical_not(np.logical_or(np.isnan(x), np.isnan(y)))
x = x[indices]
y = y[indices]

y = y - np.mean(y)

N_freq = 10000

min_freq = 0.001; 
max_freq = 4.0
height_threshold =0.7

plot_periodogram(x,y,N_freq,min_freq,max_freq,height_threshold,"periodogram")
plot_periodogram(x,y,N_freq,min_freq,max_freq,height_threshold,"ls")

   


that's a significant DC offset, did you check if the Lomb-Scargle removed the mean from the data?

from scipy documentation. Detrending defaults to "constant" which is removing the mean from the data. either specify it as false or remove the mean yourself before the Lomb-Scargle...

@TinoD I am manually removing the mean from the data before calling either function.  You will find it near the end of my code snippet
y = y - np.mean(y)

I was messing around a lot with the code and realized that I did not even check how the data looks like:

The data does not only have an offset, but a trend. This needs to be removed before any kind of frequency transformation.
I hence used the following:
df =pd.read_csv('data.csv',sep=',',comment='%', names=['x', 'Bphi','r','theta'])
df.dropna(inplace = True)
x = df['x'].values
y = signal.detrend(df['Bphi'].values)

The results are not identical, but very similar.
Scipy approach:

Astropy approach:

I would recommend a very deep look into the documentation of both functions. At the end of refining this approach, you can use np.allclose() to check if the results are acceptable.

scipy detrend is linear by default, while periodogram has constant as default detrend. Probably that's cause of small differences in the plot.

@dankal444 could be, I think a very deep reading into the documentation might help in this situation

@TinoD Thank you! I did try to detrend the data but used type = 'constant'  rather than the default type='linear'. When I use the former, I get the same results as in my original plot. Not sure why that's happening but I guess I need to dive deep into the documentation.
